# Issues combining independent survey answers in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an issue using pivot tables to combine survey results together. A bit of direction would be much appreciated!

I have the results of a survey. I include a simplification as follows:
[image]

and I would like to calculate the % of likeliness of each juice:

- Orange juice likes = 25%,
- Tomato juice likes = 50%
- Apple juice likes = 50%

and also dig deeper by filtering by fields: country, genre...

- **France** -> Orange juice likes = 50%,
- **France** -> Tomato juice likes = 0%
- **France** -> Apple juice likes = 50%

I have tried to use a pivot table for this, but I don't seem to be able to put everything together in a single table

[image]

If I add 3 filters for the juice choices, the filtered results of one column will affect the other columns

The only 2 ways I could find to do this properly was by:

- either having an independent pivot table per juice choice column and then combine the results into another table, which is tedious
- creating another table, where I convert 'like' ->1 and 'I don't like' ->0 so I can sum the values without filters

I am sure there has to be an easier way to do this? Any help would be amazing. Thanks!!!

Comment: Make lists of unique values like countries, juices, gender etc and then calculate results using countifs() etc

Comment: Actually your table is already pivoted.  The juice names should have been in values instead of column names.  Therefore pivot option is not working for you.  In the present shape of data, individual formulae will work.  However, if you are comfortable using POWER-QUERY, the job of unpivoting and then analysing with pivot table option would be much easier.

Comment: See the steps for solving this in power query, below in the answer proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the table in GET & Transform (Excel 2016) i.e. **POWER QUERY**

[image]

Transform - Unpivot last three cols, to get like this (see GIF screenshots)

[image]

Load this table back into excel to perform your calculations

[image]

Desired results

[image]

Comment: Great point about the table being already "pivoted". I did not think about that
I don't know about power query, but I don't mind learning about it. I am a Mac user. Is this an add-on? Thanks

Comment: It is to be added for first time only through excel add-ins, it is one of the most powerful features of excel.

Comment: You have neither accepted nor upvoted, does that mean are you still looking for formula way of doing it? If so, i may try that. Regarding data in a TIDY format there is a good article for `r` learners, I found that one most logical way for defining a correct data format.  If you are interested I can suggest you that.

Comment: Yes, please send me that article @AnilGoyal

Comment: [see this link](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) please. Easy but very useful. There are three interrelated rules which make a dataset tidy:
Each variable must have its own column.
Each observation must have its own row.
Each value must have its own cell.  See chap-12 of [this book]